# How to choose the location of equation numbering?

Tags: equations, numbering

The location of the equation numbering is placed automatically. How is it possible to choose where should it be? For example in the attached picture the index G.13 appears at the bottom, how can I put in the second line?
I tried to work with \nonumber but didn't manage to.[image]

code:

```
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&\widetilde{K}(x_{\perp},\, y_{\perp},\, z_{\perp},\, z_{\perp}^{\prime})\,=\,\frac{\alpha_{s}^{2}}{16\pi^{4}\left((X^{\prime})^{2}Y^{2}-X^{2}(Y^{\prime})^{2}\right)}\left(\frac{(Y^{\prime})^{2}}{Z^{2}}-\frac{(Y^{\prime})^{4}X^{2}}{(X^{\prime})^{2}Z^{2}Y^{2}}-\frac{Y^{4}(X^{\prime})^{2}}{Z^{2}X^{2}(Y^{\prime})^{2}}+\frac{Y^{2}}{Z^{2}}\right.\\
&+\frac{(X^{\prime})^{2}Y^{2}}{Z^{2}(Y^{\prime})^{2}}-\frac{X^{2}}{Z^{2}}-\frac{(X^{\prime})^{2}}{Z^{2}}+\frac{X^{2}(Y^{\prime})^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}}+\frac{(X^{\prime})^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}Z^{2}}-\frac{(Y^{\prime})^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}}-\frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}(Y^{\prime})^{2}}\\
&\left.+\frac{X^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{(X^{\prime})^{2}Z^{2}}+\frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}(Y^{\prime})^{2}}-\frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{(X^{\prime})^{2}}-\frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}}+\frac{(Y^{\prime})^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{(X^{\prime})^{2}Y^{2}}\right)\ln\left(\frac{X^{2}}{(X^{\prime})^{2}}\right)+\left(x_{\perp}\leftrightarrow y_{\perp}\right),\\
\end{split}\end{equation}
```

Comment: What environment are you using to create this monstrous equation?

Comment: \begin{equation}\begin{split}
....
\end{split}\end{equation}

Comment: Would you mind posting the code, so we don't have to re-type everything? (A *full* code, please!)

Comment: of course. I will edit the question. However, this case happen in many cases while I wrote my thesis and the question is general.

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Also, rather than posting code snippets it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, your code should compile as this makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I propose one of these three  solutions:

Either use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, which aligns equations on the leftmargin, and an `aligned environment. It requires $4$ lines for the equation to fit between margins.

Or use the `flalign` environment from `amsmath`. It requires only $3$ lines, and the placement of the tag in on the middle line, using `\notag  on the 1st and last lines.

Or use the `split` environment, and `\mathrlap` for the end of the third line which is a little too long, whereas it doesn't require space for the equation number.
I also simplified your code, replacing `(…^{\prime})^2` with a simple `…'^2`, and for a better spacing, I replaced the many `\left( … \right)` pairs with  `\biggl( … \biggr)`, or `( … )`, if they were not necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}\widetilde{K}(x_{ ⊥ },\, y_{ ⊥ },\, z_{ ⊥ },\, z_{ ⊥ }^{\prime}) = {} & \frac{\alpha_{s}^{2}}{16\pi^{4}(X'^{2}Y^{2}-X^{2}Y'^{2})} \biggl[\frac{Y'^{2}}{Z^{2}}-\frac{Y'^{4}X^{2}}{X'^{2}Z^{2}Y^{2}} - \frac{Y^{4}X'^{2}}{Z^{2}X^{2}Y'^{2}} \\%
          & + \frac{Y^{2}}{Z^{2}} + \frac{X'^{2}Y^{2}}{Z^{2}Y'^{2}} - \frac{X^{2}}{Z^{2}} - \frac{X'^{2}}{Z^{2}} + \frac{X^{2}Y'^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}} + \frac{X'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}Z^{2}} \\ %
          & - \frac{Y'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}} - \frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}Y'^{2}} +\frac{X^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}Z^{2}}+\frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}Y'^{2}} \\
          & - \frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}} - \frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}} + \frac{Y'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}Y^{2}}\biggr] \ln\biggl(\frac{X^{2}}{X'^{2}}\biggr) + (x_{ ⊥ }\leftrightarrow y_{ ⊥ }),
      \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \bigskip

    \begin{flalign} & \widetilde{K}(x_{ ⊥ } ,\, y_{ ⊥ },\, z_{ ⊥ },\, z_{ ⊥ }') = \frac{\alpha_{s}^{2}}{16\pi^{4}(X'^{2}Y^{2}-X^{2}Y'^{2})} \left[\frac{Y'^{2}}{Z^{2}}-\frac{Y'^{4}X^{2}}{X'^{2}Z^{2}Y^{2}} - \frac{Y^{4}X'^{2}}{Z^{2}X^{2}Y'^{2}} + \frac{Y^{2}}{Z^{2}} \right. \notag\\%
        & + \frac{X'^{2}Y^{2}}{Z^{2}Y'^{2}} - \frac{X^{2}}{Z^{2}} - \frac{X'^{2}}{Z^{2}} + \frac{X^{2}Y'^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}} + \frac{X'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}Z^{2}} - \frac{Y'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}} - \frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}Y'^{2}} \\ %
      & +\frac{X^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}Z^{2}}+\frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}Y'^{2}} -\frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}}-\frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}}+ \frac{Y'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}Y^{2}}\biggr]\!\ln\biggl(\frac{X^{2}}{X'^{2}}\biggr)+(x_{ ⊥ }\leftrightarrow y_{ ⊥ }),\notag
    \end{flalign}
    \bigskip

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     & \widetilde{K}(x_{\perp},\, y_{\perp},\, z_{\perp},\, z_{\perp}^{\prime}) = \frac{\alpha_{s}^{2}}{16\pi^{4}(X'^{2}Y^{2}-X^{2}Y'^{2})}%
    \biggl[\frac{Y'^{2}}{Z^{2}}-\frac{Y'^{4}X^{2}}{X'^{2}Z^{2}Y^{2}}%
    -\frac{Y^{4}X'^{2}}{Z^{2}X^{2}Y'^{2}}\mathrlap{+\frac{Y^{2}}{Z^{2}}}\\
    {}+{} &\frac{X'^{2}Y^{2}}{Z^{2}Y'^{2}}-\frac{X^{2}}{Z^{2}}-\frac{X'^{2}}{Z^{2}}%
    +\frac{X^{2}Y'^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}}+\frac{X'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}Z^{2}}%
    -\frac{Y'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}Y^{2}}-\frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{Z^{2}Y'^{2}}\\
    {}+{} &\frac{X^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}Z^{2}}+\frac{Y^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}Y'^{2}}%
    -\frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}}-\frac{(X-Y)^{2}}{X^{2}}%
    +\frac{Y'^{2}(X-Y)^{2}}{X'^{2}Y^{2}}\biggr]\!\ln\biggl(\frac{X^{2}}{X'^{2}}\biggr)%
    +(x_{\perp}\mathrlap{\leftrightarrow y_{\perp}),}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well... I tried your solution and it works for the particular example I wrote but unfortunately not in general. Is it correct that it is not possible to control the location of the numbering while I use the syntax "\begin{equation}\begin{split} ....\end{split}\end{equation}"?

Comment: @Yair: I  modified the  1st solution, and added a 3rd one, with `split`. It has a small overflow into the margin, but this may be adjusted with the margin. I don't know how to control the placement of the equation number, except playing with `\mathrlap`. Of course my code is just a sort of template to show what can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I would typeset this using an `align` environment from the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. By default, this puts an equation number on each line but you can turn this off by adding `\notag` before the `\\` that marks the end of each line.

This might be a personal thing, but I don't like using `\left(...\right)` because I think that most of the time this results overly large delimiters. Instead I use one of`\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, `\Biggl`, ..., `\Biggr` as these give finer control over the size of the brackets. In any case, I think that you are using `\left` and `\right` far too much:) Similarly, I have removed all of the `\,` because TeX knows far more than I do about typesetting mathematics and I prefer to trust it. I would also move the `\ln` term into the numerator with the `\alpha_s^2`.

With this in mind here is how I would write your code -- note that I have removed many of the unnecessary braces etc as this makes it easier to red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}\notag
  \widetilde K(x_\perp,&y_\perp, z_\perp, z_\perp^\prime)
          =\frac{\alpha_s^2\ln\frac{X^2}{(X^\prime)^2}}{16\pi^4\bigl((X^\prime)^2Y^2-X^2(Y^\prime)^2\bigr)}
           \Bigl(\frac{(Y^\prime)^2}{Z^2}-\frac{(Y^\prime)^4X^2}{(X^\prime)^2Z^2Y^2}-\frac{Y^4(X^\prime)^2}{Z^2X^2(Y^\prime)^2}+\frac{Y^2}{Z^2}\\
  &+\frac{(X^\prime)^2Y^2}{Z^2(Y^\prime)^2}-\frac{X^2}{Z^2}-\frac{(X^\prime)^2}{Z^2}+\frac{X^2(Y^\prime)^2}{Z^2Y^2}+\frac{(X^\prime)^2(X-Y)^2}{X^2Z^2}-\frac{(Y^\prime)^2(X-Y)^2}{Z^2Y^2}-\frac{Y^2(X-Y)^2}{Z^2(Y^\prime)^2}\\\notag
  &+\frac{X^2(X-Y)^2}{(X^\prime)^2Z^2}+\frac{Y^2(X-Y)^2}{X^2(Y^\prime)^2}-\frac{(X-Y)^2}{(X^\prime)^2}-\frac{(X-Y)^2}{X^2}+\frac{(Y^\prime)^2(X-Y)^2}{(X^\prime)^2Y^2}\Bigr)+x_\perp\leftrightarrow y_\perp,\\\notag
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Finally, is there a reason why you have not simplified this formula? For example, there are many terms with `Z^2` as their denominator.

Comment: The point is that I want to do it without changing the location of the log.

Comment: @Yair If you don't want the `\ln` next to the `\alpha` just move it back. The main point of my post is that you can use `\notag` to suppress equation numbers.